# Pointer and char array confusion

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 char str[] {"TESTING"};
 char *p {str};
 cout << (p++, *++p);
 cout << *p++;
 cout << p;
 return 0;
}
```

It returns "SSTING"

I know maybe this post isn't exactly for stackoverflow but I can't figure out what it does, and couldn't find any documentation about it

```
 cout << (p++, *++p);
```

First time I saw round brackets with comma in cout... what's their function?

and shouldn't this line alone say "TESTING" but it seems to say only TING

```
cout << p;
```

Thank you!

Comment: the result of `(a,b,c)` is c. If that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go line by line:

```
char str[] {"TESTING"};
```

This line defines a variable named `str` of type *array of 8 chars*, and initializes it with the characters `TESTING` plus a NUL char to mark the end.

```
char *p {str};
```

This one defines a variable named `p` of type *pointer to char* and initializes it to the address of the first char of the array `str` (the first `T`). This happens because the array automatically decays into a pointer in most uses.

```
cout << (p++, *++p);
```

This line does several things. The `,` operator first evaluates the left-hand operator `p++`, that increments the pointer, now points to the `E`; then it evaluates the right-hand operator `*++p`, but that is a pre-increment operator so it increments the pointer again (it points to `S`). Finally the `*` operator accesses to the memory pointed to by `p`, the result is a `S`. And that character is printed into STDOUT.

```
cout << *p++;
```

This one is easy. The `*` operator accesses the char pointed to by `p` (the `S` again) and prints it in STDOUT. Then it increments the pointer, because it is a post-increment operator. Now it points to the second `T`.

```
cout << p;
```

And at least, this line prints the string pointed to by `p` until it finds a NUL character. Since `p` is pointing to the second `T` of your array it will print `TING`.

Putting all those outputs together you get `SSTING`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. Could you explain again the `,` operator please? Why it printed S between the two (E, S)

Comment: The `,` operator is actually simple. The expression `E, S` is evaluated as follows: first evaluate `E` and discard the result, then evaluate `S` and use the result as the value of the full expression. Usually the `E` is there for the side-effects, not for its actual value.

Comment: Evaluate means in this case... ? So basically it just prints out the second part of `,`?

Comment: @user5372775: Not exactly. Evaluate means: compute the value and run the side effects. The `++` operator (both prefix and postfix) has a side effect, that is the increment of the pointer. If you do `x = (3, 4);` that is silly and the `3` does nothing. But if you do `x = (p++, *p);` then `p` is first incremented and then it is dereferenced. It would be just like: `p++; x = *p;`.

Comment: Oh and I wonder if I could ask you about these small stuff in the site's chat (if it has) because it's not worth it creating new threads

Comment: @user5372775: I don't usually linger in the chatrooms. You can mail me, of course, but you'd have to find my address first ;-).

Comment: Well I'd be glad to contact you any way

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer, but a breakdown of what was the code doing,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str[]{"TESTING"};
    char *p{str}; // p points to: 'T'
    p++;          // p points to: 'E'
    ++p;          // p points to: 'S'
    cout << *p;   // output a single char: 'S'
    cout << *p;   // ouptut a single char: 'S'
    p++;          // p points to: 'T'
    cout << p;    // output a (char *) type pointer, AKA a C-string, "TING";

    return 0;
}
```